# Modify value according to couple of conditions

Tags: excel

I am very new to Excel and no idea if something like that is possible and if I am able to write down what I would like to achieve but let's try. Please be understanding.

I have to write down a concentration of specific reagent in an excel cell but:

1. if value is smaller than 0.1 such "message" should be left in the cell "<0.1".
2. if value is smaller than 1 it has to be rounded to two decimal places.
3. if value is greater or equal to 1 and smaller than 10 it has to be rounded to one decimal place.
4. if value is greater or equal to 10 such "message" should be left in the cell ">10".

Is smth like that doable in excel ?

Comment: It's fairly easy to write an If statement to display the formatted value in a different cell, but a bit more difficult to display the formatted value as specified in the question in the same cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

`=IF(A3<0.1,"<0.1",IF(A3<1,ROUND(A3,2),IF(AND(A3>=1,A3<10),ROUND(A3,1),IF(A3>=10,">10"))))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula, just change the cell reference A3 as needed

```
=IF(A3<0.1,"<0.1",IF(A3<1,MROUND(A3,0.01),IF(A3<10,MROUND(A3,0.1), ">10")))
```